# How do the eigenvectors of the coefficient matrix of a first order ODE system motivate this change of variables

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, change-of-variable

Given the following problem:

Solve the coupled equation
$$\dot u = 4v,\space\space \dot v =4u$$

using the change of variables $x=u+v , \space y= u- v\space \space \space $(motivated by the eigenvectors of the coefficient marix).

I've solved it but wanted to ask:
How do the eigenvectors of the coefficient matrix motivate this change of variables?
Is there a general "rule" for going from the eigenvectors of the coefficient matrix to a change of variables?

The coefficient matrix is:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 4 \\ 4 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$.

Eigenvalues are 4 and -4 with eigenvectors $\{[1,0]^T, [0,1]^T\}$ and $\{[1,-1]^T\}$, respectively.

Comment: You might want to check what you mean with the first eigenvector. The suitable linear combinations are provided by the left eigenvectors (row vectors under multiplication from the left, usually you compute only the right eigenvectors).

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Would you mind spelling it out for me? @LutzLehmann

Answer (score 1):

If you have a linear system $\dot w=Aw$, and a left eigenvector $\alpha$ of $A$, $αA=\lambda α$, then this applied to the ODE system gives
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(αw)=αAw=λ(αw).
$$
This now is one scalar differential equation in $x=(αw)$. With a basis of left eigenvectors, one can transform the system this way into a system of independent scalar DE.

Here the matrix is symmetric, the left eigenvectors are the transposes of the right eigenvectors, and $\{(1,1),(1,-1)\}$ is a basis. Thus $x=u+v$ and $y=u-v$ will lead to independent scalar DE. Their solution, transformed back to the original canonical basis, will then be solutions of the given system.